# Django Rest Framework default image field value returns Validation

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, vue.js

We are using REST on our development and there is a feature of a site management on our app. Where the a name, description, title and icon will come from the API. We also have an admin interface on another front-end app that makes changes on the API.

Here is **models.py**:

```
class Website(models.Model):

    icon = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Here is **serializers.py:**

```
class WebsiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the **views.py**:

```
class WebsiteViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    model = Website
    queryset = Website.objects.filter()
    permission_classes = []
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer]
    serializer_class = WebsiteSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset.first())
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data)
```

My issue is the icon. It works fine when you are updating the icon. However it returns **'The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'** validation error when you did not change the icon..

This is an example of what is being returned when you get the data of the API:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "icon": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/upload/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7_2017-02-23_%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%886.02.42_zbAld6c.png",
    "name": "Hello",
    "second_name": "World",
    "description": "Bacon Loren Ipsum Porsum"
}
```

I think the issue here is that when we do not change the icon on the front-end, the URL string value is the one being returned. How do we solve this?

P.S.

- We are using vue.js on our front-end
- DRF version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your error, I think problem is that `ImageField` is a required field. So you should use `blank=True` for skip validation in a form. You also might need a `MultiPartParser` for parsing an Image.

```
class Website(models.Model):

    icon = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

[DRF parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)

Comment: This will work if the icon field is not involved in the JSON being requested to the DRF. This can be a solution but what if I don't want to remove the 'icon' key on my JSON request

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada it should work with empty key like `icon: ''` , did you try it?

Comment: Oh ok sure, I'll try it ASAP